# Does Kafka Streams library kill idle StreamThreads?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

Say, KStream topology is simple: input topic -> process -> output topic. Partitions of input topic = 4.

If there is a single instance of app running with `num.stream.threads=4`, all 4 StreamThreads are utilized.

If a second instance is launched (with `num.stream.threads=4`), stream tasks are now distributed between the two. Task 0_1 and 0_2 on first instance, Task 0_3 and 0_4 on second instance.

On first instance, does kafka streams library kill the threads which were running 0_3 and 0_4 so far?

Comment: Kafka-Streams does not kill idle stream threads, threads are still running, but without any active assigned task. you could see that either from logs, or from threads profiler like VisualVM, or using kafka-consumer-groups.
from logs you could see the following: 1) for threads with assigned partitions: `Handle new assignment with: New active tasks: [0_1]`, 2) for threads without - `Handle new assignment with: New active tasks: []`

Comment: @VasylSarzhynskyi yes I had come to same conclusion, but I was hoping that Kafka had some strategy to close them later. Otherwise, as more instances are created, there are more and more idle threads. This forces developer to specify a different thread count as number of instances grow, which means app has to be aware of the environment.

Comment: I see your concern, but as for me it's logical to update `num.stream.threads` (it's only configuration, without code changes) with increased number of app instances

Answer (score 0):

For your case when input topic has only 4 partitions, what will happen When starting `8` instances with `num.stream.threads=1`?

4 instances become idle but not be killed. They are remaining and get assign a task if any of other already assigned instance goes down.

So, same thing happens when you start multiple treads in one instances. In your case, 8 treads in 2 instances 4 per each. same scenario happen I will explained above. 4 of your threads getting idle and remain idle until it is getting a task by going down other instance.

more reference :

- [streams-faq-scalability-maximum-parallelism](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/faq.html#streams-faq-scalability-maximum-parallelism)
- [kafka-streams-internals-StreamThread](https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-kafka-streams/content/kafka-streams-internals-StreamThread.html)

> Let’s take an example. Imagine your application is reading from an input
> topic that has 5 partitions. How many app instances can we run here?
>
> The short answer is that we can run up to 5 instances of this
> application, because the application’s maximum parallelism is 5. If we
> run more than 5 app instances, then the “excess” app instances will
> successfully launch but remain idle. If one of the busy instances goes
> down, one of the idle instances will resume the former’s work.

You can see more information of threads by set up metrics referring [this](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/monitoring.html#thread-metrics)